# How can I control in KDE on which desktop an application started from commandline will appear?

Tags: linux, command-line, kde, kubuntu, kde-4

I am using a script to start an application (with GUI, i.e. windows) in KDE. However, the window will always appear on the currently used desktop. I would like to define which desktop the application will appear to be able to just run in invisible in the background. How can I do this for KDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
kstart --desktop <number> application
```

e.g.

```
kstart --desktop 2 konsole
```

Comment: Yep. figured that out a couple of days ago :)